# Disabling a html element doesn't turn off the variable mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have code as below

jsf -

```
    <t:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.variable}" style="width: 95%" id="selectid" >
             <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.general_list_please_select}" itemValue="" />
             <f:selectItems value="#{bean.collectionvar}" />
    </t:selectOneMenu>

    <t:inputText id="inputid" value="#{bean.variable}" maxlength="255" style="width: 95%" />
```

js -

```
                selectelem = document.getElementById("form:selectid");
                inputelem = document.getElementById("form:inputid");
                if (condition) {
                        selectelem.disabled = false;
                        inputelem.disabled = true;
                    } else {
                        inputelem.disabled = false;
                        selectelem.disabled = true;
                    }
```

I expect the bean.variable will take the enabled element value cause the disabled value shouldn't be passed to the back end. However, it seems in jsf code, whichever comes later will over write the previous element. But the funny thing is I did the same thing in another page, and it works fine. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Struts and JSF are competing technologies... Which one is it?

Comment: good catch. I just removed struts.

Comment: Disabling client-side does not mean the server-side knows about this... And if it works in another page... compare...

Comment: get rid of `'form:'` in `getElementById`

Comment: @charlietfl, I probably need 'form:' cause during the time I also control the display of the element and it works fine, which means it find the element correctly.

Comment: @Kukeltje, server-side mapping the data based on the parameters of the session/ request. Right? If I disable the corresponding one, the parameter won't be there. Also, I compared this page with the page it is working, and I didn't see the diff. The funny thing is I am the one who implemented this on the working page. And now I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @laodado: the remarks about the form come because you tagged the question very broadly and javascript/jquery people do not know about the 'prefixing' that is done by JSF